# Is dart better than java for creating android apps?

Tags: java, android, dart

I was planning to learn dart for building android applications. But being quite comfortable with java, I am a little skeptical about learning a new language. Does dart offers any advantages over java or it's just an alternative to java just like kotlin.

Comment: This site is not for open-ended discussions like your question. For discussion, use a forums site such as CodeRanch.com. For software recommendations, use sister site *Software Recommendations Stack Exchange*.

Comment: I disagree with  @BasilBourque

Comment: @anil The issue has been addressed [on the meta site](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Ameta.stackoverflow.com+comparing+languages&t=iphone&ia=web). This site is designed to avoid open-ended discussions. Questions here are expected to have the possibility of a reasonably conclusive solution.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Dart is a programming language used by flutter, flutter is used to create cross-platform apps (for android & ios).

If your plan is to only create apps for android only you should definitely go with java, it will run and look better in almost every way.
(for more about the differences between java and flutter here is a link: https://www.javatpoint.com/flutter-vs-java, I also suggest you look it up...)

If you want to create a small app for both android and ios, you should probably go with flutter, I say small because larger projects will almost always work better with the native languge.

To sum up, if you want to build an android app, you should use the android native language - java / kotlin, if you want to build a small app for both android & ios, you should use flutter.